# Creating a textured Rectangle in OpenGL 2.1 with Qt 5.7 on Mac OSX el capitan

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, osx-elcapitan

I am working on a project where I need to create a textured Rectangle in Qt 5.7 with OpenGL 2.1. I have written this minimal example using Qt's QOpenGLWidget:

```cpp
#include <QDebug>
#include <string.h>
#include "openglwidget.h"

OpenGLWidget::OpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

}

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL() {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    /** Vertex Shader **/
    const char* vertexShader = "\
            attribute vec2 pos;\
            attribute vec2 texCoord;\
            varying vec2 TexCoord;\
            void main() {\
                gl_Position.xy = pos.xy;\
                gl_Position.zw = vec2(0, 1);\
                TexCoord = texCoord;\
            }\
                               ";
    GLint vertexSourceLength = strlen(vertexShader);
    GLuint vertexShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderObject, 1, &vertexShader, &vertexSourceLength);
    glCompileShader(vertexShaderObject);
    GLint result;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShaderObject, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result != GL_TRUE) {
        qDebug() << "Vertex Shader not compiled";
    }

    /** Fragment Shader **/
    const char* fragmentShader = "\
            uniform sampler2D texture;\
            varying vec2 TexCoord;\
            void main() {\
                vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture, TexCoord);\
                gl_FragColor = texColor;\
            }\
                                 ";
    GLint fragmentSourceLength = strlen(vertexShader);
    GLuint fragmentShaderObject = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderObject, 1, &fragmentShader, &fragmentSourceLength);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderObject);
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShaderObject, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result != GL_TRUE) {
        qDebug() << "Fragment Shader not compiled";
    }

    /** Program **/
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShaderObject);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShaderObject);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (result != GL_TRUE) {
        qDebug() << "Program not linked.";
    }
    glUseProgram(program);

    /** Upload Buffer Data **/
    GLuint VBO;
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    GLfloat vertexData[] = {
        //Position      //TexCoord
        -0.5, -0.5,     0.0, 0.0,
         0.5, -0.5,     1.0, 0.0,
         0.5,  0.5,     1.0, 1.0,
        -0.5,  0.5,     0.0, 1.0
    };
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 4 * 4 * sizeof(GLfloat),vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    /** Set Position Pointers **/

    GLint pos = glGetAttribLocation(program, "pos");
    if (pos == -1) {
        qDebug() << "Position attribute not found.";
    }
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);

    /** Set TexCoord Pointers **/

    GLint texCoord = glGetAttribLocation(program, "texCoord");
    if (texCoord == -1) {
        qDebug() << "texCoord attribute not found.";
    }
    glVertexAttribPointer(texCoord, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 4 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void *) (2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(texCoord);

    /** Set Texture **/
    int width = 4;
    int height = 4;
    GLubyte pixels[] = {
        255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,
        255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,
        255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,
        255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255
    };
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GLint textureLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture");
    if (textureLoc == -1) {
        qDebug() << "texture uniform not found.";
    }
    glUniform1i(textureLoc, 0);

    GLuint err = GL_NO_ERROR;
    while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << (void *) err;
    }
}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h) {

}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
    GLuint err = GL_NO_ERROR;
    while ((err = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << (void *) err;
    }
}
```

I am expecting this code to generate a red rectangle, instead, I am getting a black screen. I have looked at pretty much every question related to glTexImage2D on StackOverflow, and I could not seem to find an answer. I am beginning to think that it is a Qt/Mac specific problem, but unfortunately, I do not have the resources to try it on another Operating System, so I am not sure. It could just be something obvious that I am missing.

I know for a fact that the position vectors and texCoords are being sent correctly because if I change the fragment shader to this:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 TexCoord;
void main() {
    vec4 texColor = texture2D(texture, TexCoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    gl_FragColor.xy *= TexCoord;
}
```

I get

[image: this]

which is what I would expect with that fragment shader. No errors are coming out of glGetShaderiv, glGetProgramiv, or glGetError. Any Ideas?

**UPDATE** Tried it with OpenGL 3.3, still didn't work. I tried the same test that I tried above, got the texCoords to work, and the vertices to send (with a triangle this time since GL_QUADS was deprecated, and with texture() in the fragment shader instead of texture2D, since texture was deprecated). So its not an issue with the version of OpenGL I am using.

**UPDATE** So on second thought, It doesn't make much sense that it would be an operating system problem, because I know Qt uses Apple's NeXTStep api under the hood, and barring that in mind, I tried an example of a textured OpenGL object from Apple's website (written in Objective-C and Cocoa). That worked. I looked through the source code and tried to use the same opengl calls for their textures (although they were mostly the same), and it still didn't seem to work. So it is either a problem with Qt, or something really stupid that I am missing/misunderstanding in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question! As it turns out, you have to call glBindTexture right before glDrawArrays for it to work. Something happens between initializeGL and paintGL with Qt that unbinds the texture and binds a different one. For those who are interested, I found this out by debugging using glGetTexImage, which will be a very useful function for debugging (even though it is apparently slow).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the data type you use for your texture data:

```
GLuint pixels[] = {
    255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,
    255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255,     255, 0, 0, 255
};
```

Since you use `GLuint` for the type, and the matching `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` as the *type* argument to `glTexImage2D()`, these values will be interpreted as 32-bit unsigned values. And 255 is really a very small 32-bit value, which explains why you're getting black.

In other words, `glTexImage2D()` interprets the values you pass in as normalized fixed-point values, based on the *type*. To obtain the actual normalized value in a [0.0, 1.0] range, it will divide the value you pass in by 2^32-1 in the case of 32-bit values. So the resulting value in your case will be 255/(2^32-1) = 0.00000005937. Which is close enough to 0 to be black.

To fix this, the easiest way is that you use bytes for the type:

```
GLubyte pixels[] = {
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was actually an issue with the example I posted, In the original project, it is GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, and not GL_UNSIGNED_INT. I'll edit my question with the correct type. It still doesn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: When you tell OpenGL that your data is `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` (1byte per channel) you also have to provide that data. Currently you still have GLuint which is 4 byte. You'll have to change that to `GLubyte`.

Comment: @BDL Yeah sorry.. another difference between the example and the original project. The original code had both data types as GLubyte. Neither work.

Comment: @WilliamOliver Please don't edit questions in a way that invalidates answers that were already posted. That's not how this site works.

Comment: @RetoKoradi What should I do in this case then? Its certainly not worth adding an entirely new question.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Since I found the answer to my own question, and you were the most helpful, I will award the bounty to you after the wait period.